# How to reload a page in PHP before exit function?

Tags: php, exit

I got some code like this and the header is not working

```
    if ($variable > 0) {

   header('Location: mypage.php');

   exit;
}
```

And I need exit function, is this a bad idea?

Comment: Define "bad idea". The code you have should work. If it doesn't there is an error somewhere, likely your error logs.

Comment: exit after header is considered a good idea (in general)

Comment: not working **HOW**? "headers already sent" error?

Comment: Yes, simply is not reloading and it is not showing errors or something

Comment: Is `$variable` greater than `0`?

Comment: Yes @Sean3z is greater than 0

Comment: Chk var_dump($variable) before if check and also inside the if check ... What u get

Comment: @devpro is not showing nothing, weird

Comment: Where before if or inside the if???

Comment: before and inside the if

Comment: If its not set how can it redirect friend

Comment: @devpro it was set obviously, but I didn't paste that part because is obvious

Comment: @hail-hydra yes got it.

Comment: @devpro Sorry, I wasn't trying to be mean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code produces ***any*** output text before `header` directive then `header` directive will be ignored.

Even if `header` is located before any output (HTML or PHP), be sure not to have any characters nor spaces between beginning of PHP file and `<?php` tag.

However, there is a chance that `header` directive will be accepted even if there is output present before it, if written text is still in the PHP output buffer and nothing has yet been sent to web server. But, to be safe, make `header` the first thing before any text output.